# Pass argument in command line python script

Tags: python, selenium, command-line, parameter-passing

I am using this script to run selenium tests with report. Here reports is a folder and I want the folder name to be a variable. I am thinking of having a function (or it may not be in a function) which will return date and the folder will be named with that date. How can I pass the function output/variable to a command line?

```py
today = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y.-%H.%M")
folder = f"{today}_report"
```

`python3 -m pytest tests/test.py --alluredir=/reports`

Comment: Can you please give an example?   Did you mean you wanted to run a python script which returns a value and then you use that value as a parameter to a certain command?

Comment: Yes the first two lines are the command that will be ran before my tests, and I want the folder's value to be passed to my command line script(python3 -m pytest tests/test.py --alluredir=/reports), and instead of reports to be written value of folder. Like an fstring but in a command line. f"pytest tests/test.py --alluredir=/{folder}"